# 403 Forbidden after processed variant of image Active Storage (s3)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-s3, rails-activestorage

I am using active storage (on s3) for saving resources of my app (rails). i need generate url for existing images with changed size - i used for it - `Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.rails_representation_url(column.variant(resize: '250x250').processed, only_path: true, disposition: :inline)`
But in this peace of code - `column.variant(resize: '250x250').processed` returns

> Aws::S3::Errors::Forbidden (Aws::S3::Errors::Forbidden)

backet policy

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Id": "Policy*****4140",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "Stmt*******38628",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": {
            "AWS": "*"
        },
        "Action": "s3:GetObject",
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:s3:::my_project/*"
        ]
    }
]
```

}

How can i fix it?

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26691286/amazon-s3-bucket-returning-403-forbidden

Comment: nooo...........(

Comment: are you sure you can download a resized image from s3 like this? If yes, the only thing you can check is s3 bucket policy. Check if there is any explicit deny for any such operation.

Comment: above a left bucket policy

Comment: Any `IAM` policy configured for this bucket? 
Also check this one too https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49259650/refile-returning-awss3errorsforbidden-error/49260424#49260424. If you don't resize, can you download the images(with original size)?

Comment: yes, i can.....

Comment: Check this one too. I am out of ideas and searches. https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-ruby/issues/201#issuecomment-15149528